# Pandas: create dataframe from list of namedtuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas, therefore perhaps I'm asking a very stupid question. Normally initialization of data frame in pandas would be column-wise, where I put in dict with key of column names and values of list-like object with same length.

But I would love to initialize row-wise without dynamically concat-ing rows. Say I have a list of namedtuple, is there a optimized operation that will give me a pandas data frame directly from it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The function you want is [from_records](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).

For `namedtuple` instances you must pass the `_fields` property of the namedtuple to the `columns` parameter of `from_records`, in addition to a list of namedtuples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
   [namedtuple_instance1, namedtuple_instance2],
   columns=namedtuple_type._fields
)
```

If you have dictionaries, you can use it directly as

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict(a=1, b=2), dict(a=2, b=3)])
```

Comment: That link is broken. A short demo would also greatly improve this answer.

Answer (score 42):

In a similar vein to [creating a Series from a namedtuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005204/1240268), you can use the [`_fields`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) attribute:

```
In [11]: Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

In [12]: points = [Point(1, 2), Point(3, 4)]

In [13]: pd.DataFrame(points, columns=Point._fields)
Out[13]: 
   x  y
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

*Assuming they are all of the same type, in this example all `Point`s.*

Answer (score 9):

To simplify upon the prior answers, there is evidently no need to specify [`._fields`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields). It looks to not be necessary. This should be true especially if all input tuples are of the same type. This was tested with pandas==1.3.4.

```
> import collections

> Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
> points = [Point(1, 2), Point(3, 4)]
> pd.DataFrame(points)
   x  y
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Comment: I tried it out and it is simpler. I still prefer to use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` as it is specifically designed for tuples (supports dictionaries too but then dictionaries have their own method `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`) and it gives me more peace of mind. I understand what I am saying is subjective.