# Create new pandas dataframe and add values stored in an array of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of tuples like:

```
myArr=Ttest_indResult(statistic=array([ -5.27693006,   0.,   0.,   0.15105006,]),
 pvalue=array([  2.31902785e-06,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
     8.80460569e-01,)]))
```

I want to add the values `myArr[1][0],myArr[1][1],myArr[1][2] and myArr[1][3]` to a new data frame:

```
df_tup = pd.DataFrame()
df_tup['t']=df_tup['t'].apply(lambda x: myArr[1][x]...not sure)
```

not sure how to iterate through the array while adding a value to the column t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myArr` is not exactly a `tuple` but rather a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (see [`scipy.stats` source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/80c2d3be7064a71906fef937e633af57921ec996/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L852)), which allow to access its fields like arguments, and the names of these fields.

As in your case it encapsulates two `numpy.array` (see [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind` doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy.stats.ttest_ind)) you can use it directly as values for your new columns.

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=myArr._fields, data=np.array(myArr).T)
Out[]:
   statistic    pvalue
0   -5.27693  0.000002
1    0.00000  1.000000
2    0.00000  1.000000
3    0.15105  0.880461
```

*inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20015080/6914989)*

Comment: This Works!  Thanks.